# How can I check if a Perl scalar holds a reference to a certain subroutine?

Tags: perl

In other words, how can I check for coderef "equality"?

The smartmatch operator doesn't work [for obvious reasons](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator) (would treat it as `CODE->(ANY)`), but I've included it in the example to show what I'm after:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

sub pick_at_random {

    my %table = @_;
    return ( values %table )[ rand( keys %table ) ];
}

my %lookup = ( A => \&foo,
               B => \&bar,
               C => \&baz );

my $selected = pick_at_random( %lookup );

say $selected ~~ \&foo ? "Got 'foo'" :
    $selected ~~ \&bar ? "Got 'bar'" :
    $selected ~~ \&baz ? "Got 'baz'" :
                         "Got nadda" ;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use normal (numeric) equality (`==`), as is the case with all references:

```
Perl> $selected == \&foo


Perl> $selected == \&bar


Perl> $selected == \&baz
1
```

[Live in action here](http://ideone.com/2uVBII)

That breaks when the reference is blessed with something that overloads `==` or `0+` (which is unlikely for coderefs). In that case, you'd compare `Scalar::Util::refaddr($selected)`.

From [`man perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html):

> Using a reference as a number produces an integer representing its storage location in memory.  The only useful thing to be done with this is to compare two
>          references numerically to see whether they refer to the same location.
>
> ```
>       if ($ref1 == $ref2) {  # cheap numeric compare of references
>            print "refs 1 and 2 refer to the same thing\n";
>        }
> ```

Comment: Note that this will distinguish even between multiple instances of the same closure, even though the same underlying code is called: `for my $a (1..2) { push @x, sub { print $a } } $x[0](); $x[1](); print $x[0]!=$x[1]'`

Comment: @jpalecek : Great job with the `perldoc` reference. Thanks!